# Updating a package on php gives php7.3 is already the newest version but its not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, apt

I'm trying to update php7.3.13 to 7.3.17 on ubuntu 18.04

I have done

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.3
```

It said 7.3.17 package is unpacked but after restarting apache I still get 7.3.13 in phpinfo and php-v.

Trying apt show -a php7.3 | grep Version gives Version: 7.3.17-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

`apt-get install php7.3=7.3.17-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`
gives php7.3 is already the newest version (7.3.17-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

but still php -v and phpinfo show the version is .13

What is missing?

Comment: What is the output of `update-alternatives --query php`

Comment: update-alternatives --query php
Name: php
Link: /usr/bin/php
Slaves:
 php.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/php7.3
Value: /usr/bin/php7.3

Alternative: /usr/bin/php7.3
Priority: 73
Slaves:
 php.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/php7.3.1.gz

Comment: apt update; apt install php7. 3 --re-install give that an try